# How to query table with different table owner

Tags: sql, sql-server, installation

I have several tables with defined owner user in a SQL Server 2008 database

```
a_user.[table1]
a_user.[table2]
```

When I log in as *admin* I cannot query either table because it doesn't exist [in that user namespace].

How can I make *admin* or any other user be able to query table a_user.[table1] without referencing the user?

```
select * from a_user.table1   --> works
select * from table1 --> doesn't work, i'd like this to work
```

Comment: Which table would you like to use if a_user has a table1 and b_user has a table1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking at are *schemas*, not *owners*. The two concepts are distinct (from [SQL Server 2005 onwards](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190387%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx)).

To resolve any table name, SQL Server will look in your default schema. By default, this will be dbo. The only way to access a table without specifying a schema name is for it to be in your default schema, or for you to add a [synonym](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) for the table within your default schema.